# add/remove components in noflo-ui

Tags: noflo

I've cloned [noflo-ui from github](https://github.com/noflo/noflo-ui) and am running locally but cannot figure out how to add/remove components from the noflo-search box. Ideally, I would like to remove all components from the search results and show only a the ones from my component libraries.

The readme states that libraries can be added by modifying `preview/component.json`, but removing libraries seems to have no effect. After reading through the docs on [components](http://noflojs.org/documentation/components/) and the spec for [component.js](https://github.com/componentjs/spec/blob/master/component.json/specifications.md) I tried editing `/component.json`, and was also unable to change the results which show in the search box. Furthermore, I can't find any documentation on the `.noflo` property used in `components.json`.

Am I doing something wrong or is removing default components not an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using the bundled noflo-browser runtime (iframe). Did you rebuild after editing `preview/components.json`?

An easier way to use custom component libraries is to do a custom runtime build, for instance based on [noflo-app](https://github.com/noflo/noflo-browser-app), host it locally, and switch the runtime URL to point there.
This also works with [app.flowhub.io](http://app.flowhub.io) so no need to build & run noflo-ui locally.

Comment: I did rebuild, yes. Thanks for the suggestion to use a runtime build, I'll read up on that.

Comment: A custom runtime looks like exactly what I was looking for, thanks for the tip!

Comment: We're no longer using component.js for browser builds. This answer is up-to-date: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42998041/263570

Answer (score 1):

In addition to editing `preview/component.json`, you also have to rebuild the iframe runtime components. To do that, run:

`$ grunt build`

Note that with newer noflo-ui/Flowhub there is actually no need to build the full UI locally. You can use the [hosted Flowhub](http://app.flowhub.io/) or even the Chrome app, and simply connect it to an iframe runtime you're running somewhere else:

[image: Click on the two arrows to change the runtime]

[image: Click custom iframe URL]

[image: Select the URL you want to connect to]

The [noflo-browser-app](https://github.com/noflo/noflo-browser-app) repo gives a nice base to build these from.

Comment: We're no longer using component.js for browser builds. This answer is up-to-date: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42998041/263570