# add/remove components in noflo-ui version 0.18.0

Tags: javascript, noflo

I am running noflo-ui locally and trying to replace default set of components with my own set.
This is very similar to the question [add/remove components in noflo-ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29503440/add-remove-components-in-noflo-ui), but provided answers are not correct for current version of noflo-ui. At least there is no    `preview/component.json` in the repository anymore.

I do not want to use github nor flowhub, due to internet connection limitation.

Is there a solution for current version of noflo-ui (which is 0.18.0) ?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're talking about how to add/remove components available in the NoFlo browser runtime?

If you create a project you can add components for that project and they'll be registered with the runtime.

If you want to add components from [existing NPM modules](https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/noflo), the easiest way is by making a fork of the [noflo-browser-app](https://github.com/noflo/noflo-browser-app) project template.

Then add whatever dependencies you want into `package.json`. You can then either build and host it locally, or use the integrated functionality to push host the generated runtime at GitHub Pages.

Once you have your custom runtime URL available, you can switch to that in Flowhub with the following steps.

First click the "switch runtime" button on top right corner:

[image: Switch runtimes]

Then go to runtime selector:

[image: Select runtime button]

Choose "custom iframe URL"

[image: Browser runtime options]

Enter the URL to your custom runtime's HTML file:

[image: Runtime address]

Some more information on the browser builds in [this blog post](http://bergie.iki.fi/blog/noflo-webpack/)